# SVG tile gaps on Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, svg, textures, svg-filters

I encountered an issue with SVG tile where gaps appear when the SVG is resized

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unloco/rLfoy7bq/9/)**

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="294" height="345" viewBox="0 0 294 345">
  <defs>
    <filter id="texture4902" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feImage xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/bmcAxKs.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  result="texture-img"
               width="100" height="100"></feImage>
      <feTile in="texture-img" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" result="tile"></feTile>
      <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" in="tile" result="composite"></feComposite>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="composite" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <g filter="url(#texture4902)">
      <g>
        <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/QMunN6l.png" opacity="1"></image>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Expected:
[image]

Result:
[image]

How to fix this issue? (occurs only on Chrome)

**Info: The svg is resized by the user**

Chrome bug (?)
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1037885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the edges by doing an erode/dilate at the end of your filter. Hacky - and it distorts the shape slightly - but it's better than those big lines.

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="294" height="345" viewBox="0 0 294 345">
  <defs>
    <filter id="texture4902" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feImage xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/bmcAxKs.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  result="texture-img"
               width="100" height="100"></feImage>
      <feTile in="texture-img" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" result="tile"></feTile>
      <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" in="tile" result="composite"></feComposite>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="composite" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
      <feMorphology operator="erode" radius="1"/>
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <g filter="url(#texture4902)">
      <g>
        <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/QMunN6l.png" opacity="1"></image>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are actually lighter parts on the edges of your texture... why you only see this in chrome idk... but making your image a bit larger makes the lines go away...

`<feImage width="101" height="104"></feImage>`

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="294" height="345" viewBox="0 0 294 345">
  <defs>
    <filter id="texture4902" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feImage xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/bmcAxKs.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  result="texture-img"
               width="101" height="104"></feImage>
      <feTile in="texture-img" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" result="tile"></feTile>
      <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" in="tile" result="composite"></feComposite>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="composite" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <g filter="url(#texture4902)">
      <g>
        <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/QMunN6l.png" opacity="1"></image>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't mention that the SVG is resized by the user so it has to work correctly for any size. I tried width: 400px but the gaps were back. On Firefox, it's perfect, I think it's a Chrome bug!

Comment: yes, you are right... probably a bug... this is what the spec has to say about feTile: "Implementers must take appropriate measures in constructing the tiled image to avoid artifacts between tiles, particularly in situations where the user to device transform includes shear and/or rotation. Unless care is taken, interpolation can lead to edge pixels in the tile having opacity values lower or higher than expected due to the interaction of painting adjacent tiles which each have partial overlap with particular pixels."

Comment: Thank you for the info but I have no idea how to fix it! Anyway, I reported a chrome bug here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1037885